# How do I resolve this bundle update error when trying to use jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I'm having issues getting jekyll to run to create a GitHub Page. After following the instructions as listed in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll), I keep getting an error after I edit the Gemfile and try to run `bundle update`. The error is:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "terminal-table":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    terminal-table (>= 2.0.0)

  In Gemfile:
    github-pages (~> 215) was resolved to 215, which depends on
      terminal-table (~> 1.4)'


  I reinstalled terminal-table using 'gem install terminal-table', and listing my gems using 'gem list' I can see that I have version 3.0.1 installed, so I don't understand the error.

Thanks.
```

`Gemfile`

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"
# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
# gem "jekyll", "~> 4.2.0"
# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
gem "minima", "~> 2.5"
# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
gem "github-pages", "~> 215", group: :jekyll_plugins
# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.12"
end

# Windows and JRuby does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# and associated library.
platforms :mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby do
  gem "tzinfo", "~> 1.2"
  gem "tzinfo-data"
end

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.1", :platforms => [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]
```

`Gemfile.lock`

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.8.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    colorator (1.1.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
    em-websocket (0.5.2)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.7)
    ffi (1.15.3)
    forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    i18n (1.8.10)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jekyll (4.2.0)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      colorator (~> 1.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      i18n (~> 1.0)
      jekyll-sass-converter (~> 2.0)
      jekyll-watch (~> 2.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.3)
      kramdown-parser-gfm (~> 1.0)
      liquid (~> 4.0)
      mercenary (~> 0.4.0)
      pathutil (~> 0.9)
      rouge (~> 3.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      terminal-table (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-feed (0.15.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.7, < 5.0)
    jekyll-sass-converter (2.1.0)
      sassc (> 2.0.1, < 3.0)
    jekyll-seo-tag (2.7.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.8, < 5.0)
    jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    kramdown (2.3.1)
      rexml
    kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.0)
    liquid (4.0.3)
    listen (3.5.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    mercenary (0.4.0)
    minima (2.5.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-feed (~> 0.9)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.1)
    pathutil (0.16.2)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.6)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.0)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    rouge (3.26.0)
    safe_yaml (1.0.5)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    terminal-table (2.0.0)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
    unicode-display_width (1.7.0)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-19

DEPENDENCIES
  jekyll (~> 4.2.0)
  jekyll-feed (~> 0.12)
  minima (~> 2.5)
  tzinfo (~> 1.2)
  tzinfo-data
  wdm (~> 0.1.1)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.24
```

Comment: Post your gemfile and your gemfile.lock. When you do `gem install` you are installing to your system ruby not your local bundle. Stick to editing the Gemfile to install things for your project.

Comment: Added the gemfile and gemfile.lock above

Comment: Please try applying some code formatting to improve the readability of your question. Check the *Help* section of the text editor for details.

Answer (score 9):

Just delete the .lock file and bundle install. You will get a new one.

Comment: Working fine, Saved my time thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just change `terminal-table (>= 2.0.0)` in `Gemfile.lock` to `terminal-table (~> 1.4)`. And that seems to work in my environment. Hope this can work for you!

Comment: `Gemfile.lock` is generated from running `bundle install` and `bundle update`, so you should not update it directly.

Comment: @Ross I am new to Ruby and I might be wrong, thank you for your suggestion. However, I solved the problem above by using the method which change `Gmefile.lock` directly. I don't know why.
Just want to share it with the community.